# Wrong $_GET params using MOD rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my url more friendly, from domain/link/link.php?id=123 to domain/link/123

I have written the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It is on a .htaccess in /link folder.

In my link.php file I have:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

But the result is always "link.php" without quotes, instead of the number or string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that it is the last rule using the `L` flag, but as soon as the rewritten url is requested, it will be rewritten again.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Check if the file exists and only rewrite if it does not;
2. Restrict your rewriting rules so that it only looks for numbers.

An example of the first option:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
```

(note that I have changed `*` zero or more with `+` one or more)

An example of the second option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
              ^^^ Look for 1 or more digits
```

Comment: Twice solved my problem. It seems that the rule was executed two times as you said. A way to solve the problem could be also to rename the .php file. I used the first code because it looks very elegant and it is portable too.

Comment: @alvaromat Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link/([0-9]+)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as well as the solution provided by @jeroen . However, I will choose his answer as the one solving my problem because he explains the changes made in code and why. Thanks for helping :)